# Term for a similar word that cannot stand for it in every context?

Tags: terminology

I once learned a term meaning a similar word that cannot stand for it in every context, i.e. a synonym that doesn't work in *every* instance the original word can (*not* a hypernym). What is this term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a [plesionym.](ftp://ftp.cdf.toronto.edu/pub/gh/Hirst-NearSynonyms-95.pdf) These are near-synonyms but with subtle differences (and the entire semantic range is not necessarily part of another symbol/word, as with hypo/ernymy).

Comment: The term 'synonym' itself is normally used for what the author calls a'plesionym'. I'd say his terminology is very rarely used.